# What's the purpose of "redeem" section in PUBG mobile?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

These are items present in "redeem" section
For sale :

[image]

Same items present in below "outfit" section for sale, so what's the purpose of "redeem" section in PUBG mobile?